# how to parse the json in the request in golang?

Tags: go, prometheus, grafana

data:
Extract only typical structures

```
{
  "logs": [{
      "points": [
        [30402984,1618566621000],
        [32146400,1618566636000]
      ],
      "tags.metric": {"name": "cpu_percent"}
    }]
}
```

code:

```golang
func postHandle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var contentStruct ContentStruct
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&contentStruct)
    log.Fatal(err)
    fmt.Println(contentStruct.TagsMetric)
}
```

**question1**: 
How to design the struct?
**question2**: 
How to print and view unknown json structure?

Comment: You've asked two distinct questions. The first one is opinion based (how to design the struct), The second has already been asked and answered many times, so is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```golang
type ContentStruct struct {
    Logs []struct{
        Points [][]int64 `json:"points"`
        TagsMetric struct {
            Name string `json:"name"`
        } `json:"tags.metric"`
    } `json:"logs"`
}
```

```golang
unknown, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    return
}
fmt.Println(string(unknown))
```

---

Note that your handler terminates the program regardless of whether or not you get an error from decoding the json. You should not call `log.Fatal` in every case, only when the `err` value is not `nil`, and maybe not even then, maybe you should just exit the handler, but that's for your to decide.

```golang
func postHandle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var contentStruct ContentStruct
    if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&contentStruct); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if len(contentStruct.Logs) > 0 {
        fmt.Println(contentStruct.Logs[0].TagsMetric)
    }
}
```